# Assign a case value to a column rather than an alias

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, postgresql-9.1

This should be a simple one, but I have not found any solution:

The normal way is using an alias like this:

```
CASE WHEN ac_code='T' THEN 'time' ELSE 'purchase' END as alias
```

When using alias in conjunction with `UNION ALL` this causes problem because the alias is not treated the same way as the other columns.

Using an alias to assign the value is not working. It is still treated as alias, though it has the column name.

```
CASE WHEN ac_code='T' THEN 'time' ELSE 'purchase' END as ac_subject
```

I want to assign a value to a column based on a condition.

```
CASE WHEN ac_code='T' THEN ac_subject ='time' ELSE ac_subject='purchase' END
```

Now I get the error message

> UNION types character varying and boolean cannot be matched

How can I assign a value to a column in a case statement without using an alias in the column (shared by other columns in `UNION`)?

Here is the whole (simplified) query:

```
SELECT hr_id, 
CASE WHEN hr_subject='' THEN code_name ELSE hr_subject END
FROM hr
LEFT JOIN code ON code_id=hr_code 
WHERE hr_job='123'

UNION ALL 
SELECT po_id,
CASE WHEN po_subject='' THEN code_name ELSE po_subject END
FROM po
LEFT JOIN code ON code_id=po_code
WHERE po_job='123' 

UNION ALL
SELECT ac_id,
CASE WHEN ac_code='T' THEN ac_subject='time' ELSE ac_subject='purchase' END
FROM ac
WHERE ac_job='123'
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **complete** query.

Comment: A `case` expression's return data types must be matching! And so must a `union`'s return data types.

Comment: Please share your entire query, you're probably trying to union mismatching columns but we cant see that.

Comment: Your edit shows my answer is correct; your first two queries select an ID plus a string, whereas the third query selects an ID and a boolean. That doesn't match and so you cannot use UNION ALL on the three queries. I don't understand what you actually intend to do here, though.

Comment: Thorsten Kettner - I agree that your answer shows the problem, but my question was to assign a value to a column not using an alias

Comment: Seems your editor changed the quotes. `’` is meant to be `'` really, correct?

Comment: Yes, autocorrected - not intended.

Comment: @sibert: If it's not intended, then why not fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no alias in your presented query. You are confusing terms. This would be a [**column alias**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES):

```
CASE WHEN hr_subject='' THEN code_name ELSE hr_subject END AS ac_subject
```

2. In a [**`UNION` query**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-union.html), the number of columns, column names and data types in the returned set are determined by the *first* row. All appended rows have to match the row type. Column names in appended rows (including aliases) are just noise and ignored. Maybe useful for documentation, nothing else.
3. The `=` operator does *not* assign anything in a `SELECT` query. It's the equality operator that returns a `boolean` value. `TRUE` if both operands are equal, etc. This returns a `boolean` value: `ac_subject='time'` Hence your error message:

> UNION types character varying and boolean cannot be matched

The only way to "assign" a value to a particular output column in this query is to include it at the right position in the `SELECT` list.

4. The information in the question is incomplete, but I suspect you are also confusing the empty string (`''`) with the `NULL` value. A distinction that you need to understand before doing *anything* else with relational databases. [Maybe start here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html) In this case you would rather use [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to provide a default for `NULL` values:

```
SELECT hr_id, COALESCE(hr_subject, code_name) AS ac_subject
FROM   hr
LEFT   JOIN code ON code_id=hr_code 
WHERE  hr_job = '123' 

UNION ALL 
SELECT po_id, COALESCE(po_subject, code_name)
FROM   po
LEFT   JOIN code ON code_id=po_code
WHERE  po_job = '123'

UNION ALL
SELECT ac_id, CASE WHEN ac_code = 'T' THEN 'time'::varchar ELSE 'purchase' END
FROM   ac
WHERE  ac_job = '123'
```

Just an educated guess, assuming type `varchar`. You should have added table qualification to column names to clarify their origin. Or table definitions to clarify everything.

Answer (score 0):

The CASE expression is supposed to return a value, e.g. 'time'.

Your value is another expression `subject ='time'` which is a boolean (true or false).

Is this on purpose? Does the other query you glue with UNION have a boolean in that place, too? Probably not, and this is what the DBMS complains about.

Comment: Yes, but how is the syntax to "assign" 'time' to subject column?

Comment: There is no "subject" column in your result. There is a first and a second column. The first is an ID and the second a string. If you want this string to be 'time' or 'purchase' in your third query, then make this `THEN ’time’ ELSE ’purchase’ END`.

Comment: You can add `as subject` after `CASE ... END` in your first query to call this second column "subject". It is the first query that gives the column names in a UNION [ALL] query. (So you may also want to add `as id` after `hr_id` in that first query.)

Comment: I have tried this also, but the ac_subject is still treated as an alias,  not as a regular column. So the question remains: how do I avoid alias?

Comment: I don't follow. How is `ac_subject` supposed to be involved here at all? It is a column in table `ac`, right? So when `ac_code`, another column in that table, equals 'T' you want the resulting string to be what? 'time'? What does this have to do with `ac_subject` then?

Comment: hr_subject, po_subject and ac_subject are columns in three different tables. By using UNION ALL I can fetch this values in one query. The problem is that ac_subject is a dummy column with no values. The values must be assigned by using a condition.

Comment: But if it's a dummy column, then don't use it. If you want 'time' for ac_code=’T’ then make this `CASE WHEN ac_code=’T’ THEN `'time' ...` Simply forget about your column `ac_subject` which has apparently nothing to do with your query.

Comment: It worked simply better with a dummy column in other cases when using UNION. That is the reason of its existens.

Comment: You never need a dummy column for UNION ALL; somehow you don't understand this concept entirely it seems. As to your request: Does `CASE WHEN ac_code = ’T’ THEN ’time’ ELSE ’purchase’ END` work for you or not? If not: how is the result you get different from the result you want to get?

Comment: An example: a column with alias gives 2.000000 but with a dummy column it gives the correct decimals 2.00. Using UNION. So in my case the characters will be chopped with aliases, but not with dummy column. I get unpredictable result using alias in a UNION case. That is why I avoid mixing aliases and real columns. The question remains: Can I assign a column without using an alias?

Comment: 2.000000 and 2.00 are the exact same numeric values also known as 2. You are somehow fighting something I don't understand. You can always explicitely cast types. Sorry, I just don't understand what you are trying to do. Moreover 'time' and 'purchase' are strings. I don't understand what result you want rather than these. So again: Does `CASE WHEN ac_code = ’T’ THEN ’time’ ELSE ’purchase’ END` work for you or not? If not: how is the result you get different from the result you want to get?

Comment: When you assign a text column 2.00000 or 2.00 it does matter. I have tried to cast numericvalue::numeric(10,2) but no success.

Comment: If you have a number and want to display it in a string, then you should use `to_char` in order to format the number according to your wishes. You should not rely on some implicit conversion, if you want a specific format (e.g. five or two decimal places).

Answer (score -3):

I found the problem.

```
CASE WHEN hr_subject=’’ THEN code_name ELSE hr_subject END
```

The columns code_name and hr_subject was different length. This caused the unpredictable result. I think that aliases can work now.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: This certainly doesn't explain the error message you got. And it doesn't explain what your other problem was or what you thought to be a problem for that matter.

Comment: I do fully understand my mistake now. And I am thankful for your answers. I wanted to point on the fact that all columns must have exact the same length and type in order to get the desired result. Thank you.